How to increase root partition size. I have unallocated space after installing Ubuntu 24.04 which was left almost 75GB
How to increase the root partition size, during installation? I left remaining unallocated space. Now I want to increase / size. my 1 partition is /, 2 is home, and 3 is swap and after swap unallocated space mention with 70GB. I tried with live USB in GParted, but the resize/move buttons were disabled. also used the Disks app, but it was not working. I also swap off the swap partition .My system is fully installed.


This question is similar to: How to resize partitions?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A partition that is being used will appear with a LOCK symbol indicating it cannot be resized, which is why a live system is used (ie. you boot the live system so you're not using the partitions you've installed to, just be careful to NOT MOUNT or cause to be mounted the partitions you want to resize).  Because your unpartitioned space is NOT next to the / partition, you're going to have to MOVE some partitions first, so the space is NEXT to the one you wish to 'expand' to use the unpartitioned space.

Short answer:
Boot the Ubuntu install media in "Try ubuntu" mode
and you will be able to use e.g. gparted.
More detail: https://askubuntu.com/a/18525/289138

If your system is working properly, leave it alone.
Start gparted.
Create a new partition on ext4 filesystem.
Mount it on your ~/ , for example as Data, and you're already using the available space.
Your / has 45 gigabytes unused, so why add more gigabytes to it?
